# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Window' has no index signature?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a Factory class in Typescript, but running into the following error:

> src/ts/classes/Factory.ts(8,10): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Window' has no index signature.

I tried searching for this error, but didn't see anything that quite matched what I'm wanting to do.

The following is my Factory class.

```
/**
 * @class Factory
 *
 * @description Returns object based on given class string
 */
class Factory {
    public class(className: string): any {
        return window[className];
    }
}
```

I would rather not just suppress implicit errors in the compiler.

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated! If this is not the best way to go about doing this, I'm definitely open to changing it as well.

Comment: BTW: This is not a factory as per OOP guidelines. I don't know what you store inside the `window`, yet a factory should create objects based on some input, not select objects from some god-objects. This whole method is simply a more verbose syntax to just call `window[className` and rather pointless by that.

Comment: Souns like this might be a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, @k0pernikus. I think I was trying to make this more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The global `window` variable is of `type Window`. The `type Window` has no [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html), hence, typescript cannot infer the type of `window[yourIndex]`.

For your code to pass, you can add this interface to a non-module file:

```
interface Window {
    [key:string]: any; // Add index signature
}
```

Note that this will allow *any* property access on `window`, e.g. `window.getElmentById("foo")` will stop being an error due to the typo.

Sidenote: Relying on custom modified global variables is asking for troubles in the long run, you also don't want to typehint just for `any`. The whole point of typescript is to reference specific types. `any` should at best never be used. You should not mess with the global namespace and I also advise against relying on the global window variable.

Comment: There's no need to `declare var Window`, you can simply do `interface Window { [key: string]: any }`

Comment: where can I read more about this "novel" syntax `[key:string]` and does it have googlable name?

Comment: @DimitryK it's called `index signature`

Comment: @k0pernikus tnkx! This seems to explain it well:  https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html

Comment: "You should not mess with the global namespace and I also advise against relying on the global window variable." --

Sometimes it is necessary though, for example when a callback function name is passed as query parameter to script url (as is done in several google apis).

Answer (score 98):

Another way to index on window, without having to add a declaration, is to cast it to type `any`:

```
return (window as any)[className];
```

Comment: I believe this is a better solution. When you add `[key:string] : any;` to our interface we're basically no longer gonna have any type checking on calls to the Window interface, or whichever interface you add this to. This is not good especially when the point of using typescript is to have type checking. In this answers case, you're basically saying, I know className is part of window, so I'm explicitly casting it to any first... it's not great, but it's better. I wonder if there's an even better solution.

Comment: I also think this is a much better solution than the accepted one. Consider making this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

maybe try

> return window[className as keyof WindowType];

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do this is:

```
(<any>window).className
```

I got this issue when using `window["webkitAudioContext"]`
I resolved it with `(<any>window).webkitAudioContext`

Comment: I think this worked for you because you were using a static name (constant string), but it wouldn't work for the asker because in his case, `className` is a dynamic input. Maybe `(<any>window)[className]` could work, or in your case: `(<any>window)["webkitAudioContext"]`.