# using a destroyed view for changeDetection in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular

A private (but open source) Angular package in the organisation I work for has some code that looks like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    // do more things
  });
}
```

We implement this package in our application (the package is to introduce common components so that front-end devs across the org don't implement things multiple times, and to enforce a common design language for consistency). However, when using the component this is called in, and showing and then destroying the component repeatedly, eventually it will stop working, with this error in the console:

```
Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
```

I'm trying to find a way of making sure the code above is not being run if the component has already been destroyed. I have considered using the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle method:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.changeDetector.detach();
}
```

but I'm not sure what else I would put in there to check the view is ok. I also thought about something like:

```
if (!this.changeDetector.destroyed) {
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

but nothing like `destroyed` exists on `ChangeDetectorRef`.

What is the correct way of ensuring this error does not show and the component works, even when repeatedly showing and destroying it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the change detector is triggered right after the view is initialized? And even more so, is there a reason why it is done asynchronously via setTimeout (not sequential)?

Comment: @JeanPaulA. I'm not sure, and as I have no experience with the source, I don't think it's my job to refactor it (I also don't have time as there are other things I need to work on). There is a comment above the `setTimeout` that says: `// this has to be done to prevent the change detection tree from freaking out because we are readjusting`, and above the change detection line, there's a line which re-loads a whole load of externally loaded data into the component, which may well have changed since it was last rendered.

Comment: I understand... Is the component above a template component or a route component? How is it being used? Is it for example a template component bound to an ngFor or an ngIf? What I can think of is that there is a race condition between the ```detectChanges``` method, and the creation/deletion of the component. Also as a side note, ideally loading of data should be done via route guards (if possible) or on the ngOnInit, not afterViewInit

Comment: @JeanPaulA. it's a template component, for rendering tabular data. As far as I know, it's not using any `*ng` directives

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the best solution I have found is to use `!ViewRef.destroyed` and if that returns truthy then proceed, otherwise don't.

```
if (!(this.changeDetector as ViewRef).destroyed) {
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges()
  // do other tasks
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think destroyed does work but the syntax is like this:

```
if (!this.changeDetector['destroyed']) {
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

Then obviously, just keep the code you have on your ngOnDestroy hook.

Comment: thanks - doing this creates a fatal error while building the project, `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ChangeDetectorRef' has no index signature.`. I know I could save this by adding `[key: string]: any` to the type definition (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193262/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-type-window-has-no-index-signatur)) but this doesn't really feel like a solution if I have to modify how Angular works.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been dealing with this for a long time and it solved for me (at least until now). I have unsubscribed from all my observers, and even though this error keep appearing because I have detectChanges(); on my code.