# element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{0}' has no index signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to set the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` context properties with given Object. But it always throws:

> **element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{0}' has no index signature**

How can I resolve this problem?

```typescript
interface Attr {
  fillStyle: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern;
  font: string;
  globalAlpha: number;
  lineCap: string;
  lineWidth: number;
  lineJoin: string;
  miterLimit: number;
  shadowBlur: number;
  shadowColor: string;
  strokeStyle: string;
  textAlign: string;
  textBaseline: string;
  lineDash: string;
}

const element: HTMLCanvasElement = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.querySelector('#c');
const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = element.getContext('2d');

let attr:Partial<Attr> = {
  fillStyle: 'red',
  globalAlpha: 0.8
}

function setAttrs(target: CanvasRenderingContext2D, attr: Partial<Attr>) {
  for (let p in attr) {
    target[p] = attr[p];
  }
}
```

VS Screenshot
[image: vscode shortcut here]

Comment: it's because `CanvasRenderingContext2D` does not have any index signature like `[key:string]: string | number`  associated with it . and you are trying to access the properties through index key of type `any` . you need to add index definition like in this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193262/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-type-window-has-no-index-signatur/42193905

Answer (score 12):

For Typescript, you can't access the property of `CanvasRenderingContext2D` by index. Your object `Attr` is not accessible by index neither, so in fact you have 2 errors: `target[p]` is invalid, AND `attr[p]` is also invalid. When I say invalid, it's because the calls `target[p]` and `attr[p]` return a variable implicitly typed as `any`, which is invalid because you have the flag `noImplicitAny` set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`.

You can fix your interface, by adding the index signature `[key:string]: any;`, but you can't fix `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.

**First solution**

Desactivate the compiler rule by setting `noImplicitAny` to `false`. In `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

**Second solution**

Set the flag `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` to `true`. In `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

**Third solution**

Set everything explicitly. My preferred solution because it preserved typings:

```
function setAttrs(target: CanvasRenderingContext2D, attr: Partial<Attr>) {
    target.fillStyle = attr.fillStyle;
    target.font = attr.font;
    target.globalAlpha = attr.globalAlpha;
    ...
}
```

This way you are gaining the full type coverage, which is better!

**References:**

- [How do I prevent the error “Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type” when compiling typescript with noImplicitAny flag enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)