# Nested Object -> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react form component that I'm trying to rewrite to typescript. I am trying to retrieve an object within another object in a for loop but I keep getting the following error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type
```

I've attempted the solution presented in the following questions but I was still unable to have a working solution and I do not wish to set `noImplicitAny` to `false` in `tsconfig.json`:

1. [TypeScript: Object.keys return string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)
2. [TypeScript TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358434/typescript-ts7015-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-index-expression)
3. [element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{0}' has no index signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525389/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-type-0-has-no-index-signature).

The code in question is - The problematic area can be found near the bottom:

```
import React from 'react';

import Button from '../../UI/Button/Button';
import Input from '../../UI/Input/Input';


type Config = {
    elementType: string;
    elementConfig: {
        type: string;
        placeholder: string;
        options: {
            value: string;
            displayValue: string;
        };
    };
    value: string;
    validation: {
        required: boolean;
        isEmail?: boolean;
        minLength?: number;
    };
    valid: boolean;
    touched: boolean;
    fieldActive: boolean;
    // [key: string]: string | Object;
}

interface SignInFormProps {
    isSignIn: boolean;
}

interface SignInFormState {
    controls: {
        email: Config;
        password: Config;
    };
    isSignUp: boolean;
    [key: string]: boolean | Object | Config;
}


class SignInForm extends React.Component<SignInFormProps, SignInFormState> {
    state = {
        controls: {
            email: {
                elementType: 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type: 'email',
                    placeholder: 'Your Email',
                    options: {
                        value: '',
                        displayValue: ''
                    },
                },
                value: '',
                validation: {
                    required: true,
                    isEmail: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                fieldActive: false
            },
            password: {
                elementType: 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type: 'password',
                    placeholder: 'Password',
                    options: {
                        value: '',
                        displayValue: ''
                    },
                },
                value: '',
                validation: {
                    required: true,
                    minLength: 6
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                fieldActive: false
            }
        },
        isSignUp: true
    }

    private activateField = ( controlName: keyof SignInFormState['controls'] ) => {
        do stuff...
    }

    ...

    render() {
        const formElementsArray: {id: string, config: Config}[] = [];

        // ################ The config value is causing the error ################
        for ( let key in this.state.controls ) {
            formElementsArray.push({
                id: key,
                config: this.state.controls[key] as Config
            });
        }

        let form = formElementsArray.map( formElement => (
            <Input
                blur={ ( event ) => this.disableFocus(event, formElement.id) }
                changed={ ( event ) => this.inputChangedHandler(event, formElement.id) }
                elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
                elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
                fieldActive={formElement.config.fieldActive}
                focus={ () => this.activateField(formElement.id) }
                invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
                key={formElement.id}
                shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation.required}
                touched={formElement.config.touched}
                value={formElement.config.value} />
        ));
```

If anybody has any ideas on how to resolve this while having clearly defined types and without using any then that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there isn't a nice way to do this and it's still in discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500

Below are 2 potential ways to solve your issue.

1. Declare the key outside of the loop:

```js
const formElementsArray: { id: string; config: Config }[] = [];
let key: keyof typeof this.state.controls;
for (key in this.state.controls) {
  formElementsArray.push({
    id: key,
    config: this.state.controls[key],
  });
}
```

2. Use Object.keys & cast the key to the desired type:

```js
const formElementsArray: { id: string; config: Config }[] = (Object.keys(
  this.state.controls
) as (keyof typeof this.state.controls)[]).map((key) => ({
  id: key,
  config: this.state.controls[key],
}));
```

#### You could also make it clearer by using an enum for the control key

```js
enum ControlKey {
  email = "email",
  password = "password",
}

interface SignInFormState {
  controls: {
    [key in ControlKey]: Config;
  };
  isSignUp: boolean;
  [key: string]: boolean | Object | Config;
}
```

then

1b.

```js
const formElementsArray: { id: string; config: Config }[] = [];
let key: ControlKey;
for (key in this.state.controls) {
  formElementsArray.push({
    id: key,
    config: this.state.controls[key],
  });
}
```

or

2b.

```js
const formElementsArray: { id: string; config: Config }[] = (Object.keys(
  this.state.controls
) as ControlKey[]).map((key) => ({
  id: key,
  config: this.state.controls[key],
}));
```

Hope this helps