# How to use libraries installed via <script> tags in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, facebook-instant-games

I'm trying to create a Facebook Instant HTML5 application in React.

As per their [Quick Start documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started/quickstart), they want me to install their SDK using a script tag, like so:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.3.js"></script>
```

I've created my app using `create-react-app`. I've placed that snippet inside `/public/index.html` so it looks like:

```
...
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable javascript to run this app.</noscript>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.3.js"></script>
...
```

They also provide the following snippet:

```
// Once all assets are loaded, tells the SDK 
// to end loading view and start the game
FBInstant.startGameAsync()
  .then(function() {
  // Retrieving context and player information can only be done
  // once startGameAsync() resolves
  var contextId = FBInstant.context.getID();
  var contextType = FBInstant.context.getType();

  var playerName = FBInstant.player.getName();
  var playerPic = FBInstant.player.getPhoto();
  var playerId = FBInstant.player.getID();

  // Once startGameAsync() resolves it also means the loading view has 
  // been removed and the user can see the game viewport

  game.start();
});
```

Which I've placed in `src/index.tsx'`.

This then gives me errors, saying:

```
  'FBInstant' is not defined  no-undef
```

Which likely means that the library is not being installed properly / brought into the proper namespace so that my React code can access it.

How can I get around this? Facebook tells me *not* to download and include it myself - they'll reject my app.

> **Important notes:**
>
> Do not download and add the SDK to your bundle as it will be rejected in later steps.
>
> This is a new way to build games on Facebook and does not support the Graph API.

So it seems I must use these `<script>` tags. How can I make React recognise it?

Comment: Maybe try to add it in head tag

Comment: I think this article will help you a lot: https://dev.to/abvishek/publish-react-appcreate-react-app-on-facebook-instant-game--6j4

Answer (score 1):

Once you have added the `fbinstant` script tag in the `index.html`

In your `src/index.tsx`, Add this to the top (before your snippet):

```
const FBInstant = window.FBInstant;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you explained, you're getting this error because the typescript compiler does not recognize `FBInstant`, Since it is not installed.

However in this case seems all you need is to make the compiler ignore these warning. The most suitable in my opinion is export it to a seperate `js` file (and not `ts` / `tsx`), since it is a javascript code. Than import it as any node module.

If you don't like this option, alternative methods can be:

1. including the SDK code on your `index.html`, right after your `script` tag
2. Using `@ts-ignore` to suppress typescript errors
3. define `FBInstant` before the SDK script (more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193262/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-type-window-has-no-index-signatur))

```
interface Window {
  [key:string]: any; // Add index signature
}
const FBInstant = (window as Window)['FBInstant'];
```