# Return type in a factory method

Tags: typescript, generics, factory-pattern

Given the following class hierarchy, if and how can I map concrete handler instance type to specific event class instance?

```
class Event {}

class EventA extends Event {
  constructor(public readonly value: number) {
    super();
  }
}

class EventB extends Event {
  constructor(public readonly message: string) {
    super();
  }
}

abstract class EventHandler<T> {
  public abstract run(): T;
}

class EventAHandler extends EventHandler<number> {
  constructor(private readonly event: EventA) {
    super();
  }

  public run() {
    return this.event.value + 1;
  }
}

class EventBHandler extends EventHandler<string> {
  constructor(private readonly event: EventB) {
    super();
  }

  public run() {
    return this.event.message + ' world!';
  }
}

class EventHandlerFactory {
  static createHandler<T extends Event>(event: T) {
    if (event instanceof EventA) {
      return new EventAHandler(event);
    }

    if (event instanceof EventB) {
      return new EventBHandler(event);
    }

    throw new Error('Not implemented!');
  }
}

const event = new EventA(1);

// T in createHandler is inferred as EventA
const handler = EventHandlerFactory.createHandler(event); // EventAHandler | EventBHandler

const result = handler.run(); // string | number -> should be number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/MYGwhgzhAECiBuBTAdgF2gbwL4CgekhgRVQEFpEAPVFAEyKTUx2mmAHtkJUAnAV2Cp2PABQAHPgCMQAS2DQeiMLU4gAntHhgQfRAC5oyPgFtJiHgEpmrVhD5jzIiwG4W0XLnzgocRqgBCFNR0DCTWbJzc-ILC4lKy8orKqhrGiFBgAOb60FEyyJlWGG629o4ubh54YJJRYIJs3qFoABJgyLQg5gA8ACoAfOES0nLQNXUN-MhOBr2ungQ+xGikbR1dPEE0Hc2oa509Rqbmg8WsHFy8AkKiYjwyWjQKSirI6hR+BstkRSW5ZaIKqxPKxhgkFHxpr8bM9UHweMhoKgABYyCAAOkQfnRWh0iGgAGpoABGVzAnALJq+Ej+fYbLYhamtdoHHjdPIFU5uC5Ra6xO4PMBPJKvd5YkhfPz+aE2OwOQFk9x4UHxUZTJzhViKOEIpGojHitDotIZbKE6AAcmgAHdhCBaABCC2KqpeQhMvYsjYAMXqNw0Z1yqCFo2ASRodJ6vQZOw9-REhtQsxlrBkADNoAm-NB8tx2sBEOwM99SCmbNr4YjkIhrR7Vl7HImgTYQTZ05nEznLvnC8WpWWtYgdVWax7aQ3RE3FeS-iieOxa9Xa7AePPRBaAHLsdAyYxiLppNCIR0W5uunnoTsAXkMo5LImJFRwAHpn9Bo-k2OHEJHNmiu2m5iKLQYy7KQ+CROgyITtAN7fL+voxDwajomGSgRhOWYkC40CvnWv7QAAPmOv54Bezx2CA6A3tB6zmOi6o4XhHKZERhgmGYmwALSDBAyLsHw9rQGY7HHDwOBAA)

What I would like, is to have `handler` inferred (or to be) `EventAHandler` instead of union type (without type assertion `as`), so I could determine the type of a result of a specific handler.

Comment: You can set the return type of `createHandler` to `EventHandler<T>` but you will need to use `as` inside the function itself.

Comment: It's hard to know what your event handlers *do* after they are constructed since in your example they have no methods.  As a general OOP idea, it's good if the type `A` or `B` only matters for the purposes of instantiation and you can return a general `EventHandler` type which doesn't care if it's `A` or `B`.  But I don't know if that makes sense in your use case.

Comment: Here's a similar question I answered a few days ago about typing an abstract factory pattern.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66501501/10431574  There I am declaring the return type as `EventHandler<T>` with an assertion in the function body. (needed because `T` could be `EventA | EventA`, `EventA` with some extra properties, etc.).

Comment: When you only have two types you can avoid a lot of issues by using overloads, but that is not scalable.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I've updated my question. Overloads seem to work for now, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing that...

Comment: If you know `event` to be of type EventA why do you even use `createHandler` and not `new EventHandlerA()`?

Comment: @Mati Ok your update makes it clear that you are dealing with two classes `EventAHandler` and `EventBHandler` which would be "not compatible" were it not for the generic `T`.  So that's a little different than a classic abstract factory pattern.  (But you still may want to check out [this article](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory) which explains the concept really well).  So I believe you do need either overloads of assertions to get the return type as `EventHandler<T>`. Note that your `if (event instanceof` checks will refine the variable `event` but not the type `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional types to make this work, though you will have to do a bit of casting:

```
type EventHandlerFromEvent<T extends Event> =
  T extends EventA ? EventAHandler : EventBHandler;

class EventHandlerFactory {
  static createHandler<T extends Event>(event: T): EventHandlerFromEvent<T> {
    if (event instanceof EventA) {
      return new EventAHandler(event) as EventHandlerFromEvent<T>;
    }

    if (event instanceof EventB) {
      return new EventBHandler(event) as EventHandlerFromEvent<T>;
    }

    throw new Error("Not implemented!");
  }
}
```