# Angular 11 strict mode how do you compare the to objects by property in a loop

Tags: angular, typescript, strict

I have am trying to upgrade a library to version 11, strict mode. The code can be found here works when strict is not enforced and in prior version of angular. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fsnmjo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodel%2Fmember.ts.  I have defined a method in the Member class to determine if 2 objects are "equal".

In my application, a member is equal if some of the properties match up.

I have tried two different approaches to solve the problem, "equalsV1" and "equalsV2".

equalsV1 produces the following error.

> Error in src/app/model/member.ts (17:17) Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Member'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Member'.

equalsV2 produces the following error:

> Error in src/app/model/member.ts (32:17) Type 'Extract<keyof this,
> string>' cannot be used to index type 'Member'.

My question is how do you compare the to objects by property without explicitly citing each property, i.e. memberTocompare.id === this.id is not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to change the following:

```
if (memberToCompare[key] !== value) {
                return false;
            }
```

to

```
if ((memberToCompare as any)[key] !== value) {
                return false;
            }
```

I got the clue for Thayne's answer to [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Window' has no index signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193262/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-type-window-has-no-index-signatur)

My complete code answer is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2tjpxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodel%2Fmember.ts

If any one has a better solution I would love to see it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could go with ye ole faithful `JSON.stringify`

```js
let obj1 = {t: 1};
let obj2 = {t: 1};
let obj3 = {t: 2};
let obj4 = {t: 1, x: 1};
let obj5 = {t: 1, x: () => {}};

let result1 = obj1 == obj2;
let result2 = JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
let result3 = JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj3);
let result4 = JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj4);
// note that this is true as methods are not string-ified
let result5 = JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj5);

console.log({result1, result2, result3, result4, result5})
```

Comment: This answer does not work the case of let obj1 = {t: 1, x: ['el1']} let obj6 = {t: 1, x: []} would need to be true and it is false